# Stateful integer generation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, generator, state, monads

I'd like to write a Haskell function to generate integers. The function would return 1 the first time it is called, then return the next integer each subsequent time the function is called.

In Python I've used the idea of generators — an integer generator might look something like this:

```py
def intGen():
    x = 1
    while True:
        yield x
        x += 1

integer = intGen()

# Use the generator
next(integer)    # 1
next(integer)    # 2
next(integer)    # 3
```

How do I accomplish something like this in Haskell? I know I probably need the State monad, but I'm not quite sure on how to set that up; I am fairly new to monads.

Comment: Usually one would just use something like `[1..]` and then map over it, zip it with other values, or index it since your `intGen` is basically the same as a lazy infinite list of integers starting at 1.  You can use the state monad, but I feel that it'd be overkill here.  Your use of `next` implies mutable state, though, and you can do that with the state monad or using something IORefs if you wanted it in the IO monad.  It really depends on your application.

Comment: This looks like an X/Y problem. What is the end goal you're trying to achieve? I second @bheklilr ; probably the usual way to do this is to have one function that returns an infinite list of integers, and another that consumes that list and does stuff with it. It's hard to say without knowing what the full program is meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell is pure, function can't generate different data on same arguments.

If you really want to use it, you should use `IO a` or `ST a` data, like `IORef a` and `STRef a`.

But you could use pure methods in different way:

```
intGen = [1 .. 10]

intRes = map next intGen
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `IORef`s, you could do something like

```
import Data.IORef
import Control.Monad ((=<<))

type IntGen = IORef Int

intGen :: IO IntGen
intGen = newIORef 1

next :: IntGen -> IO Int
next gen = do
    val <- readIORef gen
    writeIORef gen $ val + 1
    return val

main :: IO ()
main = do
    integer <- intGen
    -- f =<< m == m >>= f
    print =<< next integer
    print =<< next integer
    print =<< next integer
```

Or you can use the `State` monad to do this purely:

```
import Control.Monad.State

next :: Monad m => StateT Int m Int
next = do
    val <- get
    put $ val + 1
    return val

app :: StateT Int IO ()
app = do
    let stprint = liftIO . print
    stprint =<< next
    stprint =<< next
    stprint =<< next

main :: IO ()
main = void $ runStateT app 1
```

In the second one, your initial value is the `1` supplied to `runStateT`, so it's more flexible in that you can start from different values.

---

All this being said, usually when you need lazily generated integer values, a list is the way to go.  For example, I might have something like

```py
def processFile(directory):
    integer = intGen()
    for fname in os.listdir(directory):
        full_fname = os.path.join(directory, fname)
        if os.path.isfile(full_fname):
            i = next(integer)
            new_fname = '{}-{}'.format(i, fname)
            os.rename(full_fname, os.path.join(directory, new_fname))
```

but in Haskell I'd prefer to write something like

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Directory
import System.FilePath

processFiles :: FilePath -> IO ()
processFiles directory = do
    contents <- getDirectoryContents directory
    files <- filterM doesFileExist $ map (directory </>) contents
    forM_ (zip [1..] files) $ \(i, fname) -> do
        let newFName = show i ++ "-" ++ fname
        renameFile (directory </> fname) (directory </> newFName)
```

Comment: Your type signature for `next` is missing its `Monad m` context and therefore gives a type error.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks for that.  This is what I get for posting code without testing it first.